# modular problem in arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic

hello can someone please help me to solve this problem:

---

2008 mod 71,

---

9 square mod  41,

---

34 suare mod 71

---

b)determine all a and b that verify

---

a square mod  41=40

---

b square mod   71=20

---

this is my answer:

---

a) 2008 mod 41=40

---

2008 mod 71=20

---

9 square mod  41=40

---

34 suare mod 71=20

---

b) i noticed that a=9 is a solution for : a square mod  41=40

---

and b=34 is a solution  for : b square mod   71=20

---

but the problem require finding all the solution .can some one please help me .

Answer (score 1):

As $41$ is a prime number, $\mathbf Z/41\mathbf Z$ is a field/ In any field, a quadratic polynomial has at most 2 roots. In particular, an element has at most 2 roots, which are opposite. The polynomial $x^2-40$ has $9$ as a root, hence $-9=32$ is the other root.

Same argument for $x^2\equiv 20\mod 71$ since $71$ is prime.